# Web2py SQLFORM in HTML

Tags: python, web2py

I am following Web2py's book on SQLFORM in HTML.
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#SQLFORM

However, I cannot seem to figure it out. I have set the hidden field `name="_formname"` and its value to `test`. The form seems to not be processed. Here is my code:

test.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
       <li>Your name is <input name="name" /></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_formname" value="test" />
</form>
```

controller/default/test.py:

```
def test():
form = SQLFORM(db.person)
if form.process(formname='test').accepted:
    session.flash = T('Succeeded.')
    redirect(URL('index'))
elif form.errors:
    response.flash=T('Form has errors.')
return dict()
```

model/db.py:

```
db.define_table('person',
Field('name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

Comment: What are you code on test.html file (view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the book example includes the following:

```
form.process(session=None, formname='test')
```

In the above, setting `session=None` disables the hidden "_formkey" field, which is used for protection against CSRF attacks and double form submission. However, in your code, you did not set `session=None`, which means when the form is processed upon submission, it is expecting to receive the hidden "_formkey" value. When the value is not found, the processing fails, though it will not generate any `form.errors`, so your error condition will not be triggered. To replicate the book example exactly, you must set `session=None`. Otherwise, if you want to retain the CSRF protection (which is a good idea), you can add the following to the form HTML:

```
<input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="{{=formkey}}" />
```

You will also have to modify the controller function to return the formkey value for use in the view:

```
def test():
    ...
    return dict(formkey=form.formkey)
```

Comment: I got an error saying there's no attribute formkey in SQLFORM.

Comment: The `formkey` attribute will only exist *after* calling the `.process()` method, and only if you do not set `session=None`.

Answer (score 1):

You need put the HTML code on a view called test.html

and the code:

```
 session.flash = T('Succeeded.')
```

change it to:

```
response.flash='Succeeded.'
```

T() Look for a defined string to translate and I dont see a string called Succeeded. on languages files.

Try on your view file only:

```
{{=form}}
```

On this way web2py generate automatically the form for you, isn't required code the form manually

Comment: Note, it is OK to set `session.flash = T('Succeeded.')`, even if there is no "Succeeded." entry in the language file. Any string not already in the language file will be added automatically, and then you can go in and add the translation (if you do not add a translation, the string will simply be displayed untranslated -- you won't get an error).

Comment: Yes I did put my HTML code on a separate file in the views folder. I just didn't state it here.